# How can I receive the data stream from Bluetooth and add it to LinkedHashMap<>?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-bluetooth

I am beginner in Android and I have a problem with receiving the data stream sent from Bluetooth by RfcommSocket and add it to LinkedHashMap ? I use the code below but it doesn't work and I don't know, how can I deal with it?

```
public class BluetoothConnectionThread extends Thread{
public static final int MESSAGE_READ = 9999;
private final BluetoothDevice btDevice;
private BluetoothSocket btSocket;
private InputStream inStream;
private OutputStream outStream;


Map<Integer, Byte[]> linkedHashMap = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, Byte[]>();

private static UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("ae3fdfc0-8bd1-11e5-8994-feff819cdc9f");
 private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            String address = null;
            switch (msg.what) {
                case MESSAGE_READ:
                    byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;

                    String readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);

                    break;

            }
        }
    };

public BluetoothConnectionThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
    this.btDevice = device;

    try
    {

        btSocket = this.btDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        btSocket = null;
    }
}

 public void ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
        this.btSocket = socket;
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;


        try {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) { }

        inStream = tmpIn;
        outStream = tmpOut;
    }


public void run() {

    BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().cancelDiscovery();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[32];  
    int bytes; 

    try {
        btSocket.connect();

        bytes = inStream.read(buffer);
        mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();


    } catch(IOException ex) {
        try {
            btSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public void write(byte[] bytes) {
    try {
        outStream.write(bytes);
    } catch (IOException e) { }
}

public void cancel() {
    try {
        btSocket.close();
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In answer to why it's not working, you are not adding any values to the hashmap.

Depending on how you are selecting the key Integer, I have just used a static int for demonstration purposes, but this isn't the best way to go about this. If this is how you are generating the key I would suggest a List.

```
static int intKey = 0;
```

In your `case MESSAGE_READ:`

```
byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
linkedHashMap .put(intKey, readBuf)
intKey++;
```

I suggest you examine other ways of doing this, or as you do not seem to have a clear idea of how or why you are using a linked hash map.